# Angular.js: Get a variable from a Utility function into a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service on my angular.js app that creates a variable (filteredDataGlobal) in it's scope (self) and has another function to return that variable.

```
.service('Utilities',function(){
    var self = this;

    self.someFunction = function(){
      ///does calculations then assigns the results in a variable (filteredDataGlobal)
      self.filteredDataGlobal = finalResults;
    }

    self.getFilteredData = function(){
        return self.filteredDataGlobal;
    };

}
```

The problem is self.someFunction takes time to happen (calculations made after an http request) so that when you're in a controller that has the Utilities service and try to access the self.filteredDataGlobal variable like so, it's logged as undefined

```
.controller('MyController', function(Utilities) {

    var self = this;

    self.filteredData = Utilities.getFilteredData();

    console.log(self.filteredData);

})
```

How would I 'watch' for self.filteredDataGlobal to be ready in the Utilities function before I use it in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 methods that i know of.

1. callbacks
2. promises(preferred)
3. broadcast and eventHandlers

1- you put the code in a function and pass that into your service, then run that function when your variable has been prepared. something like:

```
.controller(..function(..){
    $scope.callback= function(){
        ....
    }
    someService.someFunction(params, callback);
})
```

and in your service:
    .service(...function(..){
        var someVar = value;
        callback();
    })

2- use the promise api to return a promise from your service into your controller. and use the `.done` function to know when the service has returned the data.

```
.service(.., ['$q',.., function($q,..){
    var dfd = $q.deffered;
    if(someVar == set)
        dfd.resolve;
    else
        dfd.reject;
    return dfd.promise;
}])
```

and in cotroller:

```
.controller(..function(..){
    someService.someFunction(..).then(function(){
    });
});
```

3- create an event in service. and broadcast it to rootScope. then check it in your controller to see if that particular event has occurred with `.on`. then run the controller code(that uses that variable).

```
.service(..function(..){
    someFunction(){
        $rootScope.someVar = value;
        $rootScope.broadcast('event-name');
    }
})
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller(..function(..){
    $rootScope.on('event-name', function(events, args){
        //use the variable someVar here.
    }
})
```

Note: this is not an actual code that you can copy/paste and use, it's just to give you the idea of how it works. hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, but for #2 I'm getting an error: Can't find variable: $q

Comment: `$q` is service. you need to inject it in your service before you can use it. i've updated the answer. check again. and as i said, this code is not ready-to-use. you'll still need to find bits and pieces from google. the code only shows the basics of "how to go about doing it".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mridul Kashyap answer. but I want to add something regarding point 2 that you can do as following:

```
app.controller("MyController", MyController); 

function MyController($scope, selectedService){
   selectedService.$promise.then(function(data){
  $scope.myData = data; 
  //fill your logic here. 
   }
}
```

if you do like that, you ensure that you fill your $scope variables when the promise is resolved